# Download OS X from Windows to install on Mac from USB

Tags: install

Trying to install Windows along with OS X I ended up erasing all the data on my MacBook Air. Right now I have one empty parition, so, I tried to install from internet - pressing Control + Option + R during turning it on. My internet connection is being disconnected often, and during component download - it is being disconnected (already the 3rd time) and after the connection is back after a few mins, when I click Retry it does not work anymore: from the log list I can see, that it is stuck on row

> Chunk validation failed, retrying…

I have not used OS X before, so question might be strange, but is it possible to download the OS X DVD/ISO or something else in similar format from my home PC, when make a bootable usb from it, so I can install on Mac?

As I Googled, I just found info that perhaps I can download from App Store? Is that true, and if so can I download that for free? e.g. providing my original Mac's ID or something, or I have to pay for it?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do a clean install of OSX from the recovery utilities when they load after control + option + R? Or restore from back up?

Comment: The OP already said why Internet Recovery is not working.